# Как составить запрос в данном случае?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть две базы данных(Область и общая информация про установки), нужно вывести район, количество юзеров в этом районе, количество установок на протяжении года и общее количество установок в каждом районе в одном запросе.
Общее количество установок в районе получилось сделать, а дальше он мне одно и тоже выводит через count. Уже ничего сделать не могу 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы запрос нам предлагаете с картинки отсканировать и текстом представить?

Comment: "Есть две базы данных" - две базы или таблицы?